# Java Change array elements order based on Specific columns

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexing

I have the following array is extracted from a file:

```
[ Car , House , Bike , Index0, Motor, Ski , Index1 , Hello ]
```

I am trying to reorder this array in a way where I force specific elements (index0 -> 0 and index1 -> 1) to specific positions like so:

```
[ Index0 , Index1, Bike , Car, Motor, Ski , House, Hello ]
```

So far I am able to extract the info, read the array and get the correct index but can seem to know how to continue in replacing the elements:

```
    static void loadHeaderSettingName() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Loading the header settings name [Value][ColIndex]");
    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.getRow(0);

    for (Cell cell : row) {
        headerArray.add(cell.getStringCellValue().trim());
    }

    String index0="Index0";
    String index1="Index1";

    System.out.println(headerArray.toString());

    for (int i=0; i <headerArray.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println(headerArray.get(i) + " " + i);

        if (headerArray.get(i).equals(index0)) {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve as following

```
String index0 = "index0";
    int index0_NEW_POSITION = 0;

    String  index1 = "index0";
    int  index1_COLUMN_NEW_POSITION = 1;

    int arraySizeBeforeColumnReordering = array.length;
    System.out.println("BEFORE: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(array));

    for (int i=0; i <array.length; i++ ) {

        if (array[i].equals(index0)) {
            int original_position = i;
            String tmp_original_postion_0 = array[original_position];
            array[original_position]=array[index0_NEW_POSITION];    
            array[index0_NEW_POSITION] = tmp_original_postion_0;
        }

        if (array[i].equals(index1)) {
            int original_position = i;
            String tmp_original_postion_0 = array[original_position];
            array[original_position]=array[index1_COLUMN_NEW_POSITION]; 
            array[index1_COLUMN_NEW_POSITION] = tmp_original_postion_0;
        }

        }

    int arraySizeAfterColumnReordering = array.length;
    System.out.println("AFTER: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(array));

    if (arraySizeBeforeColumnReordering == arraySizeAfterColumnReordering){
        System.out.println("The count of column before and after the column ordering is still the same: " + arraySizeBeforeColumnReordering);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The count of column before and after the column ordering is no longer the same");
        System.out.println("The count of column before: " +  arraySizeBeforeColumnReordering);
        System.out.println("The count of column after: " + arraySizeAfterColumnReordering);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for something like this inside your loop. But this is not a generic solution. Like in this approach, if you want to swap some other index except for 0 and 1, then you'll have to add another `if` condition

```
    for( int i = 0; i < headerArray.size(); i++ )
    {
        String temp;
        if( headerArray.get( i ).equalsIgnoreCase( index0 ) )
        {
            temp = headerArray.get( i );
            headerArray.set( i, headerArray.get( 0 ) );
            headerArray.set( 0, temp );
        }
        else if( myArr[i].equalsIgnoreCase( index1 ) )
        {
            temp = headerArray.get( i );
            headerArray.set( i, headerArray.get( 1 ) );
            headerArray.set( 1, temp );
        }
    }
    System.out.println ( headerArray );
```

Comment: Thanks @Klaus, I was also able to solve but using an array instead of ArrayList, check my answer below with validation for column count because I used over 400 columns for production files